# When i use the window.close ajax call not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have the small window in my page when click the button the window value send my controller and close the window. But when i use the window.close the controller not hit. But without window.close its hits properly. But i need that line for close the window.How i manage that?

My sample Code is give below:

```
function click() {debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my url'
            data: { status: $('#Field_Error')[0].checked },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
        window.close();

    }
```

controller:

```
  public ActionResult actionName(bool status)
   {// not hit here

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the code without window.close(); if you suspect the problem lies there?

Comment: "my controller its not" what is the actual value for 'my url'? Does it match the route for your controller+method? You probably need to add those in your question.

Comment: friderike its right my problem is in window.close. but i need that line

Comment: Yuriy i alreay try that but its not working

Comment: Do you create this window with `window.open` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `window.close` from inside success function

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'my url'
        data: { status: $('#Field_Error')[0].checked },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           alert(data.message);
           window.close();              
        }
    });
```

Ajax is async in nature. It does not wait for ajax to complete. So window.close called early w/o completing ajax.

Comment: oh sorry. Its working properly.But I need the close the window before alert message. But now its show alert i click 'ok' then only its close the window . But i try that   window.close();   alert(data.message); But the window is not closing

Comment: I need the alert message also mr.sachin

Comment: Once window is closed, remaining js won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

put the window.close in succes, jquery doesn't wait for ajax to finish, it goes on.

```
function click() {debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my url'
            data: { status: $('#Field_Error')[0].checked },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
                 window.close();
            }
        });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function click() {
  var myurl=test.php;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl',
        data: { status: $('#Field_Error')[0].checked },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           alert('successmsg');
           window.close();
        }
      });
   }
```